# ColdFusion escape JSON string

Tags: regex, json, coldfusion

I currently have a JSON string, which is constructed manually, that I can't alter. I am searching for a function to escape non valid characters within specific fields that are posted. For example:

`{"customer_notes" : "please deliver to 13/a test rd, nsw Australia."}`

While I could do a simple find and replace for the special characters, I'm hoping there might be an easier way, like a function or regex pattern.

I know I could use `serializeJson()` but from what I understand it needs to be performed on an entire object. If this isn't the case, I hope someone can correct me.

Comment: Do you want to replace non valid characters from json string? And what are the non valid characters? Adding an input and expected output will help.

Comment: Put some code what you have tried yet ..

Comment: if the string you have has characters that are illegal in JSON, then the string *isn't* JSON. Why is this string "constructed manually"? Why can you not alter it? if you are consuming a service that is supposed to provide you with JSON, get the providers of the service to make sure the string *is* JSON, otherwise their service is invalid. NB: the example you offer is completely valid JSON... it'd help if you posted something that is an example of what you're seeing that *isn't* valid. Bottom line though: don't accept something broken and try to fix. Make sure it's valid in the first instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`stringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class of java like this:

```
<cfset jsonStruct = deSerializeJson('{"customer_notes" : "please deliver to 13/a test rd, nsw Australia."}')>
<cfset objEscapeUtils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils")>

<!--- Loop over struct and escape each key value --->
<cfloop collection="#jsonStruct#" item="key">
    <cfset jsonStruct[key] = objEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(jsonStruct[key])>
</cfloop>

<!--- Convert to JSON --->
<cfset jsonData = serializeJson(jsonStruct)>
```